# I'm struggling to remove this error in my code firebase-storage

Tags: firebase, storage, firebase-storage

Uncaught TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.storage is not a function
at Module../src/firebase/config.js (config.js:20)
at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24)
at fn (hot module replacement:61)
at Module../src/hooks/useStorage.js (config.js:23)
at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24)
at fn (hot module replacement:61)
at Module../src/Components/ProgressBar.js (App.js:14)
at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6)
./src/firebase/config.js @ config.js:20
options.factory @ react refresh:6
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/hooks/useStorage.js @ config.js:23
options.factory @ react refresh:6
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/Components/ProgressBar.js @ App.js:14
options.factory @ react refresh:6
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/Components/UpLoadForm.js @ Title.js:13
options.factory @ react refresh:6
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/App.js @ bundle.js:17
options.factory @ react refresh:6
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/index.js @ useStorage.js:27
options.factory @ react refresh:6
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
my code not displaying

Comment: Could you please also share the code in the file `./src/firebase/config.js`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.